# BottomSheet or CollapsingToolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, bottom-sheet

*To keep it short: **[Is this a collapsing toolbar or a Persistent Bottom Sheet?](http://i.cubeupload.com/kQ3tr8.gif)***

First I thought it's a collapsing toolbar, but the scroll-up isn't that smooth on an collapsing toolbar and stops before expanding again.

Also Google Play Music is using bottom sheets for the same effect: [When google presented the bottom sheets they used google play music for example](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-persistent-bottom-sheets). So I think in the Gif are also bottom sheets used - but how are those working? How to archive this effect including the parallax effect?

Comment: This looks like a CollapsingToolbarLayout to me.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but have you finally found out what exactly that widget is and how to implement that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are looking for is achieved with a CoordinatorLayout. An in-depth tutorial about how to enable and manipulate these behaviors can be found here - https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Hope this gets you started in the right direction :)

Comment: Trying to get into this, hopefully I'll get the result I am looking for, thank you!

Comment: Sure! Just read that page as thoroughly as you can and see if you can adapt their work to suit your needs.

Comment: But is it right that collapsing toolbars are not scrolling smooth? That they stop scrolling on scroll up? I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: I'm not totally sure - do you mean that the scrolling animation is jittery? It could be that your device/emulator is just not cut out to handle animations well, due to hardware....